# Тонкости работы со стеком

Tags: стек

Если стек уже заполнен и в него передаётся ещё 1 элемент, то увеличивается ли он в размерах или выдаёт ошибку?

Comment: Зависит от реализации, вас какой именно стэк интересует?

Comment: Вы про который стек? Который ESP?